# How to run code repeatedly whilst program is open?

Tags: vb.net, loops

How can I run a line of code the whole time a program is open in VB? I am using Visual Basic Express 2013.

Comment: Read up on loops, especially while loops :)

Comment: In addition to iProgramIt's answer, **never** use `Application.DoEvents()`. Use a timer or a thread to keep your user interface responsive. For reference: [**Keeping your UI Responsive and the Dangers of Application.DoEvents**](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jfoscoding/2005/08/06/keeping-your-ui-responsive-and-the-dangers-of-application-doevents/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to run a whole line of code whilst a program is open, I assume you want it to be in the background. If so, you should consider looking into [threads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread(v=vs.110).aspx).

Other than that, to keep a whole line going, you can use a variety of loops, but as @RB has stated, use can use a `While` loop. To make a loop that loops as long as your program is open, you can use:

```
    While True
        'Write some code here.
    End While
```

If you want to be able to terminate that loop, you should declare a `Boolean` in your class, then do something like:

```
    While KeepLooping 'Replace KeepLooping with your variable name.
        'Write some code here.
    End While
```

As a side note, if you don't choose to utilise a thread, your program will freeze so long as the loop is active.

Comment: NONONONONO! You should **NOT EVEN MENTION** `Application.DoEvents()`! It is very bad practice to use it to keep the user interface responsive, unless you use it the right way (which never happens!). Don't teach the new people to use it. They will almost always choose the easy way.

Comment: I know I am a bit harsh, but I'm frustrated about that there seem to be an increasing amount of people using `DoEvents()` these days.

Comment: I know it's bad practice. That's why it's a side note. Edit: Oh, I see what you mean. Will remove.

Comment: Thank you. And sorry for the outburst, but I just don't understand why more and more start picking up this bad practice (not saying you do, but others).

Comment: I know, it's incredibly silly. It's an easy way, and it's what I used when I started programming, but picked up on `Thread` a while after.